# Detect numerics in string

Tags: r, string, insert, expression

I have data in the following format:

```
January 2015
2014
May 2012
2011
NA
```

Wherever there is only the year, I would like to insert "December" in front of it. But I don't want to insert "December" in front of "NA". May I know how to do this in R?

Comment: what is the structure of your object? i.e. what is `str(df)` if df is your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the below `sub` function.

```
sub("^(\\d+)$", "December \\1", df$x)
```

`^` - start of the line anchor which helps to match the boundary which exists at the start of a line.

`\\d+` - Matches one or more digits. `()` around `\\d+` helps to capture that particular digit characters. You may refer the chars present inside the capturing group in the replacement part using backrefernce. `\\1` refers the chars present inside the first capturing group.

`$` - End of the line anchor. So this regex would match the strings which has only digit chraacters.

**or**

```
sub("^(\\d{4})$", "December \\1", df$x)
```

`\\d{4}` matches exactly 4 digit chars.

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome! Can you explain how ^(\\d+)$ works? I'll approve this when the 10 mins is up